# Embedded primes in reduced rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$ be a reduced Noetherian ring. I know that $A$ has no embedded primes associated to $(0)$. It seems reasonable that then the same is true for any ideal of $A$, i.e. there are no embedded primes associated to any ideal $I\subset A$. Can you help me to prove this fact?

Comment: It seems even more reasonable that this doesn't hold. The fact you proved for $(0)$ uses that $A/(0)$ is reduced, while $A/I$ has no reason to be reduced. I leave you the pleasure to find a counterexample in an integral domain like $K[X,Y]$.